# Reversed for loop

Tags: c#, loops

I made this small nested for loop, and it shows no error in C# whatsoever, 
but when I try to run my small program I get the following error in my `TextBox`:

> System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: System.Windows.Forms.TextBox,
>   Text: Syst...

Here is my code:

```
int number = textBox.Text..ToString();
for (int row = 0; row < number; row++)
{
    for (int x = number - row; x > 0; x--)
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "X";
    }
    textBox2.Text = textBox2 + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

My result should be something like this:

---

XXXX 
XXX  
XX
X

I can't figure out what may cause this error.

Comment: What is your full exception message?

Comment: Use the debugger to step through your program.

Comment: Are you getting an exception, or a build error?

Comment: Who is giving random downvotes to all the answers?

Comment: Looks like someone doesn't like the competition in the answers.

Comment: Yea, why are most of the answers downvoted..

Comment: All the answers so far are wrong! Not me downvoting by the way!

Comment: @Tobsey: how are they wrong?

Comment: Your textboxes aren't showing errors, they're showing System.Windows.Forms.Textbox.ToString () which returns the name of the type, you want to display Textbox.Text I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
int number = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
for (int row = 0; row < number; row++)
{
    for (int x = number - row; x > 0; x--)
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "X";
    }
    textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

1. Convert TextBox Value in integer
2. Change textBox2 to textBox2.Text in second last line
3. Use textBox as multiline textbox

Answer (score 6):

You can't assign a string to a number.  You need to convert it:

```
// int number = textBox.Text..ToString();
int number;
if (!int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out number)
{
    // Handle improper input...
}

// Use number now
```

In addition, when you add the newline, you need to actually append to the `Text` property, not the TextBox itself:

```
textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: i was concentrating the whole time what i might have done wrong, while it was just a small mistake. Sometimes its good to let a third person view your code. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
textBox2.Text = textBox2 +
```

use

```
textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text +
```

in the last line.

That's it ;-)

Comment: That's only one of multiple problems...  Fixing that line still won't allow the code to compile.

Answer (score 3):

`textBox2.Text = textBox2 + Environment.NewLine;`

Should be

`textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine;`

`System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` is just class name

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a `.Text` in the second to last line. It should be:

```
textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine;
                        ^^^^^
```

or just:

```
textBox2.Text += Environment.NewLine;
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign `string` to an `int` , what you are doing as:

```
int number = textBox.Text..ToString();
```

Better option is to use `int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out number)`

**AND**

Change

```
textBox2.Text = textBox2 + Environment.NewLine;
```

to

```
textBox2.Text = textBox2.text + Environment.NewLine;
```

**Edit:**
Even if you change 2 dots to 1, it will give error for `int number = textBox.Text.ToString();` - you can't assign `string` to `int`

Comment: You can't assign a string to an integer.

Comment: Yeah - the two ".." is wrong, but even if you fix that, the line is still wrong... ;)

Comment: That won't compile, `int number = textBox.text.ToString()`

Comment: I pointed 2 dots - btw, edited my answer and have mentioned about it. so undo -1 Please.

Comment: Undo -1 Please. i removed that :P

Answer (score 2):

```
int number = textBox.Text..ToString();
```

Suppose that was a typo? Either way, check if the value is numeric first.

```
if (int.TryParse(textBox.Text, out number))
{
       //run your loop here
}
```

Also,

```
textBox2.Text = textBox2 + Environment.NewLine;
```

should be:

```
textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two dots here.

```
textBox.Text..ToString();
```

This should throw a compilation error by the way. And you can't assign it to a variable of type integer.

```
textBox2.Text = textBox2 + Environment.NewLine;
```

You have to call a method of the textbox here, presumably `textBox2.Text`.

Answer (score 1):

This might inspire you to think about this problem differently:

```
// I created a simple textbox class so I could do this in a console app
var textBox = new TextBox();
var textBox2 = new TextBox();
textBox.Text = "4";

var number = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text);
var descendingXStrings = Enumerable.Range(1, number)
                                   .Select(n => new string('X', n))
                                   .Reverse();
textBox2.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, descendingXStrings);

Console.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
```

*CW as this does not answer the question directly.*

Comment: thank you! i will try to look into this code and try to understand this, and try to create new things based on this code block